# how to pass select option value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a below code snippet

HTML

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="quan!=true">
  <select ng-model="selectedItems" ng-init="selectedItems = selectedItems + ''">
    <option ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo:quantity">{{value}}</option>  
</select>
  </div> 

<div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="submit()">Submit</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.quan=false;
 for(var a=1; a<=10; a++) {  
    $scope.arr.push(a); 
 }
 $scope.selectedItems = $scope.arr[0];
 $scope.quantity = 10; //just hardcoded
```

Here, when I click submit button, I didn't get the value whatever I have selected in the dropdown. I was getting undefined for selectedItems.

And also first option needs to be selected in the select box.

I think I'm missing something!

Comment: i know that it is type error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing to `$scope.selectedItems = $scope.arr[0];`, you need to initialize your option value `ng-init="selectedItems = selectedItems + ''"` because angular use strict comparison.

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/2/).

also you don't need to pass selected item in click event, `submit(selectedItems)`. because it is already in controller scope.

Also I would recommend changing your options structure to avoid `ng-init`.

Something like :

```
options = [{
   name: 'key1',
   value: 'value1'
}, {
   name: 'key2',
   value: 'value2'
}];
```

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/3/ , it we make ng-if condiiton, it is failing to work

Comment: @UI_Dev: because `ng-if` creates its own scope. To avoid it utilise prototypcal inheritance of javascript., which persist scope for angular. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/4/)

Comment: great :) you saved my day

Comment: if u see this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/6/ how do i differentiate each and every select dropdowns? all are showing the same value if selected

Comment: because you are creating same `html` inside `ng-repeat="product in colors"`, you are not utilizing iterator `product` to make it dynamic, I suggest to close this thread, and please ask a separate question for this.

Comment: done, please check this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204895/select-option-value-not-iterated-dynamically-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" >
        <option ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo:quantity">{{value}}</option>  
    </select>

    <div>
        <a href="#" ng-click="submit();">Submit</a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.arr = [];
     for(var a=1; a<=10; a++) {  
        $scope.arr.push(a); 
     }
     $scope.selectedItem = $scope.arr[0];
     $scope.quantity = 10; //just hardcoded
     $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log($scope.selectedItem); // you will get the selected value here, if you want it after button click. 
     };
```

Because of angular's 2 way binding, it would be available as soon as you select something. You do not have to pass it as function parameter from HTML

Comment: try this fiddle jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/3 , it we make ng-if condiiton, it is failing to work\