# select option value not iterated dynamically in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you look at the below code, how do i differentiate each and every select dropdowns dynamically?

All dropdowns are showing the same value if selected.

Requirement is I wanted to show 3 dropdowns dynamically from 1 to 10 option value (declared in array) based on the response structure - in this case, there are three products, so three dynamic dropdowns needs to be displayed.

what is the efficient way to achieve this?

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <div ng-repeat="product in colors.item">
         <div ng-if="quan!=true">
           <select ng-model="selectedItems.val" ng-init="selectedItems.val = selectedItems.val + ''">
              <option ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo:quantity">{{value}}</option>  
       </select>
    </div> 
  </div>
<div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="submit(selectedItems.val)">Submit</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
       var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.colors = {"category": "students"
"item":[
    {
    "product":{
            "name":"abc",
             "age": "24"
    }
    "boo": true
    },
    {
     "product":{
            "name":"def",
             "age": "44"
    }
    },
    {
     "product":{
            "name":"ghi",
             "age": "22"
    }
    }
  ]};
 $scope.quan = false;
 $scope.arr = [];
 for(var a=1; a<=10; a++) { 
    $scope.arr.push(a); 
 }
 $scope.selectedItems = {val : $scope.arr[0]};
 $scope.quantity = 10;
 $scope.submit = function(av){
 alert(av);
 }

});
```

[JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/8/)

Comment: why not use `ng-options`?

Comment: tried that too... was getting injector error when loading this

Comment: what is expected behavior?

Comment: it should show three dropdowns, all should have 1 to 10 value, if we select 3 in first dropdown, it should not affect the other dropdown values..

Comment: it should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/6/ but i have updated the code snippet

Comment: you have 3 different dropdowns, but you only have a single variable to store the results in.  Also, that `ng-init` doesn't make any sense, and in general, you shouldn't use `ng-init` anyway.

Comment: how we can do this dynamically instead of storing in single variable?

Comment: what is your *intent* here?  do you want an array of selected values to send to the server? or do you want the `product` to know which dropdown was selected for itself?  and if you are trying to get an array, how will you know which array element corresponds to which `product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `selectedItems` is **one** and you have `colors` as **`array`**.

You can have `selectedItems` inside `colors` like this:

```
$scope.colors.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.selectedItems = {
    val: $scope.arr[0]
  }
})
```

Now, change your `<select>` like this:

```
<select ng-model="product.selectedItems.val" ng-init="product.selectedItems.val = product.selectedItems.val + ''">
    <option ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo:quantity">{{value}}    
    </option>
</select>
```

And, `submit` be like:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.colors.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.selectedItems.val)
  })
}
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/10/)

Alternatively, you can make use of `$index` inside first `ng-repeat` to have `selectedItems` seperate than `colors`

Answer (score 0):

Provide unique id to select element like id={{$index+1}} to differentiate bewteen all the select dropdowns.

Answer (score -1):

There were few errors in the code. You have missed 2 commas in $scope.product json .

```
See updated working fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dy1vw7v5/9/